# Reconstruct 3D Transformation matrix from 2D projection matricies

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I'm working on reconstucting movement of 3D objects based on 2D orthogonal projections of that object.

Till now I'm working with two **orthogonal** projections of the object, one on the `z-x plane` and one on the `z-y plane`.

(**I want to neglect the projection to `x-y plane`.** That information is not important to me. Should that be a problem then I can easily compute the 2x3 matrix for x-y, too and add that information).

By using two consecutive frames of those projections I can compute a 2x3 transformation matrices using OpenCV's [estimateRigidTransform()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) function. The `2x3 transformation` matrices include *Rotation*, *Scalin*g and *Translation*:

$$T_{z,x} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \cos(\theta)s & -\sin(\theta)s & tz \\ \sin(\theta)s & \cos(\theta)s & tx\end{array} \right]$$

$$T_{z,y} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \cos(\theta)s & -\sin(\theta)s & tz \\ \sin(\theta)s & \cos(\theta)s & ty\end{array} \right]$$

([Here](http://nghiaho.com/?p=2208) you can find more detailed information about what exactly estimateRigidTransform() does.)

Here is a sample visualization for clarification:

[image] 
[image]

So after computing this for based on the two 2D projections I want to reconstruct a 3D transformation matrix out of this information the manipulate the 3D object. My aim is to undo the transformation that happend to the 3D object between `Frame 1` and `Frame 2`. Therefore I want to apply the 3D transfrmation matrix to the object so that it is in the same spatial position it was at when `Frame 1` was taken.

Sample 3D visualization:

$\hskip2in$[image]

I understand that a 3D transformation matrix is build up by the following logic:

$$ S = \begin{bmatrix}
 S_{x}&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  S_{y}&  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  S_{z}& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ T = \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 
 t_{x}& t_{y}&  t_{z}& 1\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$R_{x}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  \cos\theta & −\sin\theta& 0\\ 
 0&  \sin\theta &  \cos\theta& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  0& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_{y}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\theta& 0&  \sin\theta& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0& 0\\ 
 −\sin\theta&  0&  \cos\theta& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  0& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_{z}(\theta) =\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos\theta &  −\sin\theta &  0& 0\\ 
 \sin\theta &  \cos\theta &  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

(I do not want to include shearing.)

My question is how to use the information held by the two 2D 2x3 transformation matrices to construct a 3D transformation matrix that in total transforms the 3D object in the same way as the 2D matrices would if I apply them to their corresponding planes?

***EDIT:***

As suggested by [amd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd) I tried to find more constrains to reduce the number of free parameters.

I analysed the movement of the object and I found out that the **3 dominant parameters** are:

- Translation in z-direction
- Rotation around the x-axis (Pitch)
- Rotation around the y-axis (Yaw)

What can be **neglected** is:

- Translation in *negative* z-direction
- Rotation around the z-axis (Roll)

I hope that helps.

Comment: On the face of it, a complete reconstruction of the 3-D transformation doesn’t seem possible. The transformations you’re considering have 9 degrees of freedom, but the two estimated transformations of the projections only supply 8 parameters. Do you have any constraints on the possible transformations.

Comment: Also, what’s the nature of the two projections? Orthogonal vs. perspective, for instance, makes a big difference.

Comment: The projections are orthogonal. I will think about the constrains to see if we can reduce the degrees of freedom.

Comment: If you can see the same object feature in both views, you could potentially make use of that to correlate them.

Comment: @amd I edited my question and provided more information about possible constrains to reduce the number of free parameters.

Comment: Is your $T$ matrix transposed above?

Comment: @ja72 It’s consistent with the computer graphics convention of using row vectors and post-multiplying to apply a transformation, but then the rotation matrices are inconsistent with it.

Comment: Are you trying to reconstruct a rigid motion (no scaling or shearing), then? That’s what it looks like from your additions and would significantly reduce the degrees of freedom. It also imposes the constraints that the determinants of the 3-D transformation matrix and its principal minor are both 1, and that the principal minor is orthogonal.

Comment: @amd Yes I guess that a rigid transformation is what I am looking for, at least I want to exclude shearing and scaling. The projected object will most likely translate in z-direction with small rotations (pitch and yaw). There might be minor scaling too, that we can neglect. But definitely no shearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not an answer, but too long for comments.]

I wonder if you might be making the problem harder by “simplifying” it. Here’s what a few simple rigid motions look like when projected onto the $y$-$z$ plane:

- Rotation about the $z$-axis: $[x\sin\gamma+y\cos\gamma,z]$, so equivalent to the planar transformation $$\begin{bmatrix}y&z&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\gamma&0\\0&1\\x\sin\gamma&0\end{bmatrix}$$ which looks like scaling+translation.
- Rotation about the $y$-axis: $[y,z\cos\beta-x\sin\beta,1]$, equivalent to $$\begin{bmatrix}y&z&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\cos\beta\\0&-x\sin\beta\end{bmatrix}$$ which also looks like scaling+translation
- Rotation about $y$, then $z$: $[y\cos\gamma+z\sin\beta\sin\gamma+x\cos\beta\sin\gamma,z\cos\beta-x\sin\beta]$, or $$\begin{bmatrix}y&z&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos\gamma & 0 \\ \sin\beta\sin\gamma & \cos\beta \\ x\cos\beta\sin\gamma & -x\sin\beta \end{bmatrix}$$ which is more like a shear+translation. Trying to approximate this by a shearless affine transformation might not work so well.

Of concern, too, is the “free” factor of $x$ in the translation part of all of these transformations. This doesn’t really correspond to anything in the image plane and makes the resulting transformation non-affine. It’s reminiscent of the way that $z$ appears in the derivation of the perspective projection, so I wonder if you might get better results by computing a planar perspective transform for each view and trying to reconstruct the 3-D transformation from those. On the other hand, if the frame-to-frame difference is small, affine approximations shouldn’t be too bad.